# Successive prime numbers and triangles

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, triangles, triangle-inequality

Except the triplet $(2,3,5)$, I am wondering if there exists another triplet of successive prime numbers such that they do not form a triangle (each prime number corresponds to a side of the triangle).

The question may be asked otherwise:

> Are there primes $p_k, p_{k+1}$ and $p_{k+2}$, with $p_k > 2$, such that $p_k + p_{k+1} \leq  p_{k+2}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "triangle." Without stating $p_k + p_{k + 1} \leq p_{k + 2}$, I'd have no idea what you're asking. Can you give an example of three numbers, regardless of primality, that form a "triangle"?

Comment: Do you mean a Heronian triangle? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronianTriangle.html

Comment: @RobertSoupe, Absolutely not! Notice that sides of Haronian triangles are not neccessarily (never?) successive prime numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove it in a trivial way if you use the non-trivial [result proven by Jitsuro Nagura](https://doi.org/10.3792/pja/1195570997) that for $n\ge25$ there is always a prime between $n$ and $6n/5$. In that case:

$$p_{k+2}<\frac{6p_{k+1}}{5}<\frac{36p_k}{25}\tag{1}$$

On the other side:

$$p_k+p_{k+1}>2p_k\tag{2}$$

By comparing (1) and (2) you get that:

$$p_k+p_{k+1}>p_{k+2}$$

For $n\lt25$ you can do a manual check which is not a problem considering a small number of cases: (2,3,5), (3,5,7), (5,7,11), (7,11,13), (11, 13, 17), (13, 17, 19), (17, 19, 23), (19, 23, 29) and (23, 29, 31).

Obviously (2,3,5) is the only triplet that does not form a triangle.

By the way: the fact that $p_{k+1}<2p_k$ is known as [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

**EDIT:** To prove this inequality you can also use some of the weaker statements proved by Nagura in the same paper:

[image]

For example, you can choose the fact that for $n\ge9$ there is always a prime between $n$ and $4n/3$. The procedure stays the same but you'll have to do fewer manual checks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We have $p_{k+2}<2p_{k}<p_{k+1}+p_k$ for all $k\ge 4$.

Edit: The first inequality follows from a refined version of Bertrand's postulate.

Comment: Can you provide a name or reference or something like that for you equation?

Comment: @quarague Search for bounds on the $n$-th prime and inequalities here on this site. Of course, $p_k<p_{k+1}$ is trivial, so we only need the first inequality.

Comment: I think you are using $p_{k+1} < 2 p_k$ but this is sort of hard to put into a search engine. So I was wondering whether this inequality has a name or whether you could provide a link where or how this is proven.

Comment: Where $p_{k+2} < 2 p_k$ comes from?